# Bluetooth EarBuds with Mic for Voice Recognition On Raspberrypi 3

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, voice-recognition

Please has anyone had success on using bluetooth earbuds with mic for voice recognition on the raspberrypi 3.Can't seem to get the pi to use the bluetooth earbuds as both input for the speech and output through the earbuds. Tried connecting using the inbuilt bluetooth on the pi 3. Any suggestions on how to go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately,I would have to believe the inbuilt bluetooth has some problems or doesn't support that yet. By using a bluetooth dongle I was able to set the active profile to HSP and it works well. Thanks to the detailed steps explained here http://youness.net/raspberry-pi/bluetooth-headset-raspberry-pi-3-ad2p-hsp .Minimal versions needed for HSP (A2DP included) are: Bluez 5 / PulseAudio 6. Thanks